# Why do functions defined in a loop all return the same value?

Tags: javascript

I'm confused by the following JavaScript code.  I wrote a loop and defined a function inside the loop, but when I call a function defined in the loop, I only get 10 rather than the index.

Obviously, in the following code I abstracted out stuff that isn't relevant:

```
objectArray = [];
for (i = 0; i< 10; i++){
    objectArray[i] = {};   
}
for (i = 0; i< 10; i++){
    objectArray[i].get_number = function(){
        return i;    
    }
}
console.log(objectArray[5].get_number()); // returns 10 rather than 5
```

I always get 10 rather than i as expected.

Comment: What's this `objectArray[i] = {};` supposed to do?

Comment: @odedta It initialises each element to an empty object

Comment: I'm almost positive this is a duplicate, but can't find a decent target right now

Comment: This is the infamous `closure inside a loop` problem. With a closure you have access to the outer scope, so you have access to `i`. BUT (and this is the important part): You access `i` at a point of time where the loop has already finished! Solution: Use a separate scope (e.g. by creating a local copy of i at loop time) and then use the local copy inside the closure function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of JavaScript closure.  The method `objectArray[i].get_number` has direct access to `i` (not a copy of `i`).  The value of `i` lives on in memory because each method `objectArray[i].get_number` still has access to it.  There's only one `i`, and when the loop iterates it, it increases by one.  When a method `objectArray[i].get_number` accesses it, the loop has already run to completion, so it accesses the final value of `i`.

Comment: Formatting please. Use backticks.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: Also, you might want to add the solution to the problem as well. How to get around this?

Comment: @RudePeopleStepOff You can make code look more like code by using the \` character.  It's the difference between objectArray[i].get_number and `objectArray[i].get_number` - makes all the difference.